# I am trying to pip install pandas but running into some trouble

Tags: pip

In Terminal, I run the command

```
Jareds-MacBook-Pro:~ jaredamodio$ pip install pandas
```

and what results is:

```
Collecting pandas
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/52/ff/912fe03a623a70bcf297d466013a0b4f4c68c3b60f86bf226682d061fc09/pandas-0.24.2-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.5.0 (from pandas)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/17/c62faccbfbd163c7f57f3844689e3a78bae1f403648a6afb1d0866d87fbb/python_dateutil-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting numpy>=1.12.0 (from pandas)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8f/0b/1a2c21bb69138337dc079841aa4a45e5b2fc7a4260c0907f5254fb08f02e/numpy-1.16.4-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from pandas) (2013.7)
Collecting six>=1.5 (from python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six, python-dateutil, numpy, pandas
  Found existing installation: six 1.4.1
Cannot uninstall 'six'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

The issue is clearly in the last part of this message, starting with "Found existing installation: six 1.4.1 ..."

How can I get around this to install pandas?

This may be a pretty basic question; I'm very much new to this and haven't pip installed much, I appreciate any guidance you may give!

Answer (score 1):

[According to the internet](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3165), one way to get around this is to use `--ignore-installed` e.g.:

```
pip install pandas --ignore-installed six
```

or possibly:

```
pip install pandas --ignore-installed six --user
```

That said, there also seem to be very sound suggestions to install another version of Python yourself (ex. via `homebrew`) or to use a Python virtual environment to get around this issue. [These would probably be what I would recommend.]

---

*Note that there are a couple more options listed in the given link as well, in case you need them.*

---